# How can I get a full guide to choosing the right IC package?

Tags: integrated-circuit, packages, vibration, shock

I often find a variety of IC packages options for one chip.

I select among them randomly according to the availability, despite my concern about the vibration and shock reliability

I googled everywhere but still have not found a satisfying book or tutorial.

Comment: What is the target design industry, if any?

Comment: That is part of the design process. They will all have the same die but if power is involved dissipation becomes a factor. Somewhere in the design process it was decided to use SMD, through hole or something else. That is one of the main guiding factors. If you select a BGA be sure you can mount it, same for all the other packages. If it is not available in your favorite package select another source or a different part. Welcome to EE. I believe the reason you cannot find the book is it still has to be written, that would be a project for you.

Comment: thank you Rodo
commercial and industrial

Comment: thank you Gil
yeah i could not find any satisfying resources, it would be an exciting project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vibration and shock mechanical issues are common on new reflow solder joints when the thermal profile and solder process is not optimized.

These skills and whoever is assembling the board determine which package you choose for experience on “almost opens” and almost shorted from solder balls.

If you are choosing an u known or u qualified design and PCB contract Mfg source, then repetitive shocks applied to the board with random or periodic bumps within a industry standard spec such as 5g for ground or 15g or more for aerospace.  In my case it was once 100g shock 10ms for rocket instrumentation.

For automotive applications conformal coating is often used to reduce solder joint stress and reduce contamination effects.